# puremvc on winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

I cannot find any mvc framework that can cover both the web and the desktop, mobile (including iphone) except puremvc. It seems great for Winform

http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2009/07/winforms-development-made-simple-with-puremvc/

But apart from samples for silverlight, I cannot find a real example for Winform just a 10 line snippet.

I cannot ask on their forum it seems one cannot register at the moment.

Could someone could give a sample with all parts that is a bit more elaborate than just startup in main:

http://forums.puremvc.org/index.php?topic=129.0;prev_next=next

```
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        MainForm mf = new MainForm(args);
        ApplicationFacade facade = (ApplicationFacade) ApplicationFacade.Instance;
        facade.Startup(mf);
        Application.Run(mf);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log some errors, show message box, etc.
    }
}
```